# Make balance bracket with highest score

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, brackets

**Question:**

Given an array A of integers and a score S = 0. For each place in the array, you can do one of the following:

- Place a "(". The score would be S += Ai
- Place a ")". The score would be S -= Ai
- Skip it

What is the highest score you can get so that the brackets are balanced?

**Limits:**

- |Ai| <= 10^9
- Size of array A: <= 10^5

**P/S:**

I have tried many ways but my best take is a brute force that takes O(3^n). Is there a way to do this problem in O(n.logn) or less?

Comment: Is this online somewhere for testing? How large can the array be? Is there a time limit?

Comment: @KellyBundy it's from an old private contest from my school. I just added the limits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in `O(n log n)` time with a max-heap.

First, remove the asymmetry in the operations. Rather than having open and closed brackets, assume we start off with a running sum of `-sum(A)`, i.e. all closed brackets. Now, for every element in A, we can add it to our running sum either zero, one or two times, corresponding to leaving a closed bracket, removing the closed bracket, or adding an open bracket, respectively. The balance constraint now says that after processing the first `k` elements, we have:

1. Made at least `k` additions, for all integers `k`,
2. We make `length(A)` total additions.
3. We have added the final element to our sum either zero or one times.

Suppose that after processing the first `k` elements, we have made `k` additions, and that we have the maximum score possible of all such configurations. We can extend this to a maximum score configuration of the first `k+1` elements with `k+1` additions, greedily. We have a new choice going forward of adding the `k+1-th` element to our sum up to two times, but can only add it at most once now. Simply choose the largest seen element that has not yet been added to our sum two times, and add it to our sum: this must also be a maximum-score configuration, or we can show the old configuration wasn't maximum either.

Python Code: (All values are negated because Python only has a min-heap)

```py
def solve(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    """Given an array of integers, return the maximum sum achievable.
    We must add k elements from nums and subtract k elements from nums,
    left to right and all distinct, so that at no point have we subtracted
    more elements than we have added.
    """

    max_heap = []
    running_sum = 0

    # Balance will be 0 after all loop iterations.
    for value in nums:
        running_sum -= value  # Assume value is subtracted
        heapq.heappush(max_heap, -value)  # Option to not subtract value
        heapq.heappush(max_heap, -value)  # Option to add value

        # Either un-subtract or add the largest previous free element
        running_sum -= heapq.heappop(max_heap)

    return running_sum
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time by using a two-dimensional array *highest_score*, where *highest_score*[*i*][*b*] is the highest score achievable after position *i* with *b* open brackets yet to be closed. Each element *highest_score*[*i*][*b*] depends only on *highest_score*[*i*−1][*b*−1], *highest_score*[*i*−1][*b*], and *highest_score*[*i*−1][*b*+1] (and of course *A*[*i*]), so each row *highest_score*[*i*] can be computed in *O*(*n*) time from the previous row *highest_score*[*i*−1], and the final answer is *highest_score*[*n*][0].

(Note: that uses *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) space, but since each row of *highest_score* depends only on the previous row, you can actually do it in *O*(*n*) by reusing rows. But the asymptotic runtime complexity will be the same either way.)

Comment: Since the size of array A is <= 10^5, there might be an O(n.logn) or less solution. Do you have any idea on ways that this could be optimized?

Comment: I think you need to consider `highest_score[i−1][b]`, too, no?

Comment: @KellyBundy: Thanks for pointing that out; I'd forgotten that "skip" was an option! (Though I guess it's moot anyway, seeing as a better answer has been posted now?)

Comment: I don't think it's moot, it's at least useful for [testing](https://ideone.com/ZHNzzk) the other answer for correctness :-)